# PHP linear processing - script is waiting for an object to finish before proceeding

Tags: php

This may be a noob question, please consider the following script which in a nutshell corresponds to my real code:

----------------  class -------------

```
  <?php


    class BaseClass {

        public $flag;

        function __construct() {

            $this->flag = 0;

        }

        function mainMethod() {

            sleep(3);

            $this->flag = 1;

        }



        function getFlag() {

        return $this->flag;

        }


    }

  ?>
```

--------------- creating new instance -------------

```
<?php

require_once('test_class.php');

$test = new BaseClass;
$test -> mainMethod();

while($test -> getFlag() != 1) {

    usleep(1000000); // 1sec.

    echo "waiting";
}

?>
```

When the above class is instantiated, the **$flag** is set to **0** by constructor. Then the **mainMethod()** is called which sleeps for 3sec. and then sets the **$flag** to **1**. The procedural **"while" loop** below checks for the **$flag** value. Ideally it should return the string **"waiting"** 3 times before it would allow the script to finish but it doesn't. The code is executed linearly and the **"while"** loop will never execute before the **mainMethod()** finishes its sleep time (hence never echoes "waiting").

Perhaps thought I could use the **pcntl_fork()** to split the call into 2 different processes but this code runs on Win 2008. Is there an easy way to make the **"while"** loop work (asynchronously) while the **mainMethod()** is being processed ?

Thank you.

Comment: If windows supports pthreads ( I doubt it) you can use threading to accomplish this.  Notice forking runs two separate processes - threading is what you want to run twice in one pricess (eg shared data between) ...  Use a better operating system, and you won't have this problem :)  This looks promising, OS limitations not withstanding: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Comment: Can you let us know what you're actually trying to do? It's possible that you're approaching this in a way that could be completed without this requirement.

Comment: to:jprofitt - ok... to explain further, I have a script which instantiates limited number of the BaseClass objects. As soon as one of the objects finishes its task another is created in its place and so on but the total number of all "running" objects will always stay the same. If one of the objects fails for any reason (i.e.: uncaught exception, etc.) the whole process should not fail, only the "failed" object should exit with an exception message. The problem I am having right now is that I cannot even control the running state of each object (hence the above). It executes linearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for consumption in a webserver/browser, I recommend you redesign:

- Run one request, that does the real work
- via AJAX run the polling requests from the browser
- couple those two via the session

Comment: ..nope. There is no browser involved. Thanks.